# How to determine if flutter is running in simulator

Tags: flutter

Is there a call to determine if flutter is running within a simulator or a physical device?

I am scanning QR codes, and want to bypass, since the camera is unavailable.

I expected to find this in `platform.dart`[1] but it's not there.

[1]https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/platform.dart

I imagine I can create a plugin if I really need, I'm hoping it already exists.

Comment: It can be as simple as setting up an app-wide constant like `IS_REAL_DEVICE` or as complicated as plugins or even a separate main.dart files.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using the [device info plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) plugin you can get various information about the device you're running on, including 'isPhysicalDevice' for both `Android` and `iOS` (although you'll have to read them independently).

Comment: Still not a reason to do it. You don't want to push dev specific behavior in production.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Not entirely sure what you're saying, but I think you're making an assumption here, this is to enable testing/dev to use both physical devices as well as simulator when working.

Comment: That's kinda optinion-based so I won't dabate too much. But it's usually better to have configuration files instead of a `if (platform == stuff)`.

Comment: There's also the option of wrapping the platform check in an assertion so it only does it in debug mode (as that's probably all you'd use in the simulator anyways). I do see what you mean @Remi, but he's still going to have to have an if (configuration == simulator) or something anyways with a different main, and actually remember that every time he's running on a simulator he has to switch to a different configuration which is a bit of a pain especially if he's on a team with multiple people...

Comment: Yeah but that conf is not necesseraly a "isSimulator". it can also be a "hasCamera", or "checkQRCode".

Comment: True enough. And if you really want to make it robust (for testing etc) you can use dependency injection to inject a builder that builds either a camera simulator or actual camera depending on the configuration. Still, for ease of use it would probably be ideal to do the check for a normal run, although you could move the platform check to main & set hasCamera or set up dependency injection there.

Comment: Some of us run multiple devices and simulators at the same time for scaling and design consistency. Certain features like push notifications & video playback, camera aren't supported on the iOS simulator. Helps to have isSimulator

Comment: It's deprecated. You can use https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus now.

Answer (score 17):

## 2021 Update

It‘s now part of Flutter Community Plus (https://plus.fluttercommunity.dev/)

Device Info Plus Docu: https://plus.fluttercommunity.dev/docs/device_info_plus/overview

e.g.:

```
DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
if(Platform.isIOS){
  var iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
  if(iosInfo.isPhysicalDevice){...}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I Know I'm A Bit Late, But If Anyone Else Comes Here, This Can Help Them.
You Can Just Use This Package:
https://pub.dev/packages/safe_device

Add The Latest Version In Your `Pubspec.yaml` File
Then import it:

```
import 'package:safe_device/safe_device.dart';
```

Then You Can Check If Device Is An Emulator:

```
bool isRealDevice = await SafeDevice.isRealDevice;
```

Comment: Just wanted to mention, that the above answers with [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) are much more viable as it is mainted by the flutter community itself and has a lot more features. but if you aren't interested in other features and solely want to check whether the device is an emulator, my current answer is much more viable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_is_emulator

```
import 'package:flutter_is_emulator/flutter_is_emulator.dart';
....
bool isAnEmulator = await FlutterIsEmulator.isDeviceAnEmulatorOrASimulator;
```

Comment: Not the greatest solution, since it predates null safety, so the type of `isDeviceAnEmulatorOrASimulator` is `Future<bool*>*`

Comment: Since this package is discontinued. this answer makes no sense now and should be deleted / removed.

Answer (score 0):

No.
But what you can do instead is use different configurations (such as a dev configuration).

For this you can use a different `main.dart` such as `main.dev.dart` and then run it with `flutter run -t lib/main.dev.dart`

Comment: Some of us run multiple devices and simulators at the same time for scaling and design consistency. Certain features like push notifications & video playback, camera aren't supported on the iOS simulator. Helps to have isSimulator

Comment: "No", pretty much sounds like "i don't k**no**w*".
Please do proper research before answering questions.
The answer you provided, doesn't align with what the OP has asked for.