# How to detect emulator or real device in flutter? (Bluestacks, NoxPlayer, or LDPlayer)

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I want to detect the difference between an emulator and a real device. I use the device_info_plus package to determine whether the device is an emulator or a real device. It works well, but when I try to run my app and test it in Bluestacks, NoxPlayer, or LDPlayer, it doesn't work. When I run it in those emulators, the result is that it detects the device as a real device. How can I solve this problem?

I am trying to run my app on emulators such as Bluestacks, NoxPlayer, and LDPlayer to test whether it is running on an emulator or a real device. However, the emulators are being detected as real devices. How can I fix this?

Comment: "the emulators are being detected as real devices" Show the code you are using that is giving false results. You should be able to check ```isPhysicalDevice``` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866014/how-to-determine-if-flutter-is-running-in-simulator

Comment: The **isPhysicalDevice** property only works in the Android Studio Emulator. It does not work in other emulators such as Bluestacks, NoxPlayer, or LDPlayer.

Comment: The solution to my problem is not working perfectly yet, but I have already found a way to fix it. Thank you for your suggestion. [MY SOLUTION](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77139422/22005920)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution to the problem:

- Add the **[get_radio_version_plugin: ^1.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/get_radio_version_plugin)** plugin to your pubspec.yaml file.
- Get the value of radioVersion and compare it to the following values:

  - 1.0.0.0
  - "" (empty string)
  - null
- If **radioVersion** is equal to any of these values, then the device is an emulator. Otherwise, the device is a real device.

> > **Example Code :**

```
if(radioVersion == '1.0.0.0' || radioVersion == ''|| radioVersion == null){
  //Emulator
} else {
  //Real Device
}
```

[>> Image Result <<](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75QkB.png)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            log("isPhysicalDevice: ${await checkIsPhysicalDevice()}");
          },
          child: const Text("Check Is Physical Device"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> checkIsPhysicalDevice() async {
    final AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await DeviceInfoPlugin().androidInfo;
    final bool finalCondition = androidInfo.fingerprint.startsWith("generic") ||
        androidInfo.fingerprint.startsWith("unknown") ||
        androidInfo.model.contains("google_sdk") ||
        androidInfo.model.contains("Emulator") ||
        androidInfo.model.contains("Android SDK built for x86") ||
        androidInfo.manufacturer.contains("Genymotion") ||
        androidInfo.brand.startsWith("generic") ||
        androidInfo.device.startsWith("generic") ||
        androidInfo.product == "vbox86p" ||
        androidInfo.device == "vbox86" ||
        androidInfo.hardware == "vbox86" ||
        androidInfo.product == "google_sdk";
    return Future<bool>.value(finalCondition);
  }
}
```

I assure you that it is more accurate than `androidInfo.isPhysicalDevice`.

OR

Try this: [safe_device](https://pub.dev/packages/safe_device)

Comment: Have you tried testing it in emulators such as Bluestacks, NoxPlayer, and LDPlayer?